# AWS Amplify GraphQL fetches nothing on first load, works properly on refresh in NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm about ready to move off of AWS Amplify and tell everyone I ever meet to avoid it.

I have the below code to retrieve multiple choice questions from a GraphQL database. The code is  called by a page. On my local machine, on first load, with no cached data, the code below returns nothing.

Simply refreshing the page in the browser causes the code to properly fetch the data.

AWS docs are useless and I can't figure out why sometimes the same query returns nothing and sometimes it returns data.

```
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import amplifyconfig from "../amplifyconfiguration.json";
Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);

import { generateClient } from "aws-amplify/api";

import { questionMultipleChoicesByIncidentID } from "../graphql/queries";

export default async function getQuestionsByIncident(incidentId: any) {

  const client = generateClient();

  let questionSet: any;
  let questionData: any[] = [];
  let attempts = 0;


  const fetchQuestions = async () => {
    try {
      questionSet = await client.graphql({
        query: questionMultipleChoicesByIncidentID,
        variables: {
          incidentID: incidentId,
        },
      });
      questionData = questionSet.data.questionMultipleChoicesByIncidentID.items;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("getQuestionsByIncident - Error getting Questions:", error);
    }
  };

  while (questionData.length === 0 && attempts < 5) {
    await fetchQuestions();
    if (questionData.length === 0) {
      attempts += 1;
      // Wait for 300ms before retrying
      console.log("No data retrieved, retrying. Attempt number: ", attempts);
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 300));
    }
  }

  return { questionData };
}
```

I expect data to be retrieved every time this code is run, regardless of if we are refreshing from the browser or landing on the page.

Comment: I should add that this error doesn't seem to occur in production, only on my local machine.